# What is the most general Poincaré inequality?

Tags: vector-spaces, integral-inequality

Does the Poincaré inequality 
$$\int_{\Omega} |u|^p dx\leq C \int_{\Omega} |\nabla u|^p dx$$
hold if we do not have $u\in W^{1,p}_0$, but have $u\in W^{1,p}$ and $u(x_0)=0$ in trace sense at some $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ or $u\in W^{1,p}$ and $u(x)=0$ in a small neighborhood of some $x_0\in\partial\Omega$?

$\Omega$ is an open bounded set in $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

You may adapt the proof of [Wirtinger's inequality for real functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) only by assuming $u(x)=0$ almost everywhere on $\partial \Omega$ (and you probably need some extra assumption on the regularity of $\partial\Omega$). $u(x_0)=0$ is an empty condition, because functions in $\mathcal{L}^p(\Omega)$ do not need to be pointwise-defined.

Comment: Suppose the boundary is as regular as needed. I clarified the question as follows: suppose $u\in W^{1,p}$, $u(x)=0$ on some part of the boundary,  not entire boundary, in trace sense. Does Poincare inequality $$\int_{\Omega}|u|^p \leq C \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^p$$ holds? The trace makes sense now beacuse $u\in W^{1,2}$.